# Update everything in a database that is like something in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a database and i have a home URL that I want to change into another one. The problem is that this home URL is used in a lot of table and in a lot of column.

So is there a MySQL request that do something like :

`UPDATE * SET * = REPLACE(*, 'old-url', 'new-url') WHERE * LIKE '%old-url%'`

?

Have a good day ! :)

Comment: You have to do this one table and column at a time.

Comment: Try [interconnect/it Database Search and Replace](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid... But if there no other solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the plugin "Go Live Update URLS". You just enter the old & new URL and select the tables you want to replace the value.

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/

**Back-up your database before executing the replacement!**

Comment: Amazing! Glad it helped you :)